# JavaFX Animation: Move Shape (Star) randomly

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-8

My problem is, that after every keyframe the x- and y-Position of the rectangle should change by random.
Right now only when I start the program, the rectangles position is set by random, but not in the animation itself.

How can I do this, thanks a lot...

```
public class TimeLines extends Application {

private Rectangle rectBasicTimeline;
private Timeline timeline;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Do Animation");
    int x = new Random().nextInt(500);
    int y = new Random().nextInt(400);
    rectBasicTimeline = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 50);
    rectBasicTimeline.setFill(Color.RED);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
            final KeyValue kx = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.xProperty(), x + 200);
            final KeyValue ky = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.yProperty(), y + 200);
            final KeyValue kScale = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.scaleXProperty(), 2);
            final KeyValue kFade = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.opacityProperty(), 0);
            final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), kx, ky, kScale, kFade);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            timeline.play();
      }
    });

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, rectBasicTimeline);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: I updated my answer with the requirement you mentioned in your "answer" below. I used 4-handed star instead of rectangle. You can change it to 5-handed easily if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Roland, no need to create multiple Timeline. Reclicking the button just restarts the timeline with new KeyFrame:

```
public class StarFall extends Application
{

    private Polygon star;
    private Timeline timeline;
    private final double shs = 5.0; // Star Hand Size
    private final Random random = new Random();


    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage )
    {
        // init shape
        Pos initPos = getRandomPos();
        star = new Polygon();
        star.setLayoutX( initPos.x );
        star.setLayoutY( initPos.y );
        star.setFill( Color.YELLOW );

        // the shape
        star.getPoints().addAll( new Double[]
        {
            0.0, shs * 3,
            shs * 2, shs * 2,
            shs * 3, 0.0,
            shs * 4, shs * 2,
            shs * 6, shs * 3,
            shs * 4, shs * 4,
            shs * 3, shs * 6,
            shs * 2, shs * 4
        } );

        // init timeline
        timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount( Timeline.INDEFINITE );
        timeline.setAutoReverse( true );

        // init button
        Button btnStart = new Button( "Do Animation" );
        btnStart.setOnAction( ( e ) -> playNextKeyFrame() );

        Button btnStop = new Button( "Stop Animation" );
        btnStop.setLayoutX( 200 );
        btnStart.setLayoutX( 0 );
        btnStop.setOnAction( ( e ) -> timeline.stop() );

        // init scene with root
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane( btnStart, btnStop, star );
        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800, 600 );

        // show
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void playNextKeyFrame()
    {
        // generate next random start and end positions for star
        Pos startPos = getRandomPos();
        Pos endPos = getRandomPos();

        // initial values (resetting)
        star.setLayoutX( startPos.x );
        star.setLayoutY( startPos.y );
        star.setScaleX( 1 );
        star.setScaleY( 1 );
        star.setOpacity( 1 );

        // target values
        KeyValue kx = new KeyValue( star.layoutXProperty(), endPos.x );
        KeyValue ky = new KeyValue( star.layoutYProperty(), endPos.y );
        KeyValue kScaleX = new KeyValue( star.scaleXProperty(), 3 );
        KeyValue kScaleY = new KeyValue( star.scaleYProperty(), 3 );
        KeyValue kFade = new KeyValue( star.opacityProperty(), 0.0 );

        // delay animation before start. Use this instead of THread.sleep() !!
        timeline.setDelay( Duration.millis( random.nextInt( 2000 ) + 100 ) );

        // restart timeline with new values
        timeline.stop();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add( new KeyFrame( Duration.millis( 3000 ),
                ( e ) -> playNextKeyFrame(), kx, ky, kFade, kScaleX, kScaleY ) );
        timeline.play();
    }


    private Pos getRandomPos()
    {
        int x = random.nextInt( 500 );
        int y = random.nextInt( 400 );
        Pos p = new Pos();
        p.x = x + 200;
        p.y = y + 200;
        return p;
    }


    private class Pos
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thousands thanks to you ... that is so brilliant, you are the best !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the random numbers and hence the location once and use it all the time. What you need to do is to perform the animation cycle once and then create a new animation when the current one finishes.

Example:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TimeLines extends Application {

    private Rectangle rectBasicTimeline;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Do Animation");

        int x = new Random().nextInt(500);
        int y = new Random().nextInt(400);
        rectBasicTimeline = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 50);
        rectBasicTimeline.setFill(Color.RED);

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                play();

            }
        });

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn, rectBasicTimeline);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void play() {

        double x = new Random().nextInt(500);
        double y = new Random().nextInt(400);

        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        // cycle count = 2 because of autoreverse
        timeline.setCycleCount(2);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        final KeyValue kx = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.xProperty(), x + 200);
        final KeyValue ky = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.yProperty(), y + 200);
        final KeyValue kScale = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.scaleXProperty(), 2);
        final KeyValue kFade = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.opacityProperty(), 0);
        final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kx, ky, kScale, kFade);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
        timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {
            // create new animation after this animation finishes
            play();
        });
        timeline.play();

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't suggest this approach though, e. g. you run into problems with multiple timelines when you click the button multiple times. But I have no information what you're trying to do, so I'll leave it at that.